# Python 3: How to move an item from list x to list y and remove it from list x?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, append

I am trying to `.append` a random card from list `Deck` to `MyHand`, while removing it from `Deck`.

```
import random

Deck = []
MyHand = []
CardsPicked = 0

for Cards in range(1, 101):
    Deck.append(Cards)

while(CardsPicked < 8):
    MyHand.append(random.choice(Deck))
    CardsPicked = CardsPicked + 1
```

THINGS TO KNOW: I've been able to add the card, but not remove it.

I tried doing `Deck.remove(random.choice)`, but it said that the choice wasn't in the deck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyHand.append(Deck.pop(random.choice(range(len(Deck)))))
```

(`pop` takes an index to remove and returns the item removed)

Something closer to your code would be:

```
card = random.choice(Deck)
Deck.remove(card)
MyHand.append(card)
```

Comment: good answer for a very strange implementation of deck.deal ;P +1

Comment: How about `random.randrange`?

Answer (score 3):

you typcally shuffle the deck

```
Deck.shuffle()
```

then you just remove cards from one end

```
hand.append(Deck.pop())
```

normally when you deal cards do you draw  from random places in the deck or do you shuffle and pass the cards around

Comment: It's `random.shuffle(Deck)`. It's kind of inefficient to shuffle the whole deck if you only need 8 random cards, but quite possibly *less* inefficient than 8 calls to remove an item from a random place within the list, which is the obvious alternative. Shame `random` doesn't have a "swap random choice to the end" function.

Comment: I tried doing that but I know I'm not doing it right. Can you put it in better context so I can understand and apply it to my code.

Comment: you `shuffle` the deck after you have placed the cards in it ... you replace your `hand.append` line with this` hand.append` line